# No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'. on adding third party library

Tags: android

So I am getting this error when I add this library in my gradle file.

```
compile 'com.miguelcatalan:materialsearchview:1.4.0'
```

This is my gradle file

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.gnr.kumar.varun.songapp.songapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.miguelcatalan:materialsearchview:1.4.0'

}
```

How can I prevent this, can anyone please suggest something ?

Comment: Change `compileSdkVersion 23`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'
```

You should change your `compileSdkVersion`

```
compileSdkVersion 23 // compileSdkVersion is the version of the compiler used in building the app
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
```

Then **`Clean-Rebuild-Sync`** Your App .